# Submit data with ajax & jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to submit some data via ajax. It is not a form, but there are couple of radiobuttons on the page that belond to a form.

I need to detect which of the two radio buttons is selected when I send ajax request, without submitting the form and append that value to my ajax post. How do I do that?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "op="+act+"&radioButton="+id
});

<input class="radioB" type="radio" value="all" name="users" checked> All
<input class="radioB" type="radio" value="some" name="users"> Some
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more options how to check which of the buttons is selected e.g.

```
$('.radioB:checked').val(); // returns the value or just val() without :checked
$('.radioB').is(':checked'); // can be used in a loop with if statement
```

So it would transform into:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "op="+act+"&radioButton="+$('.radioB:checked').val()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var act = $(".radioB[name='users']").val();
```

will save `all` or `some` into `act`

Answer (score 1):

This should give an idea of what to check for in regards to the getting radio button status (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-if-certain-radiobutton-is-checked).  As to passing that data on via jquery ajax, google that.

Answer (score 1):

Just [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) and send the form data:

```
$.post('ajax.php', $('#myFormId').serialize());
```